# PHP - Run 1 Query with multiple WHILE Statements

Tags: php, sql, html

I have a PHP page that runs a SQL query against an Oracle Database

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1;
```

and for output -  I want to run 5 WHILE statements depending on the value of the recordset - something like this....

I want 1 Query and 5 WHILE statements based on value of recordset - How do I do this? To my knowledge, you can only run 1 WHILE statement based on 1 Query... ??

```
 // MOVIE='movieA'
 while ($row = oci_fetch_array($query, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {

 // data here

 }

// MOVIE='movieB'
 while ($row = oci_fetch_array($query, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {

 // data here

 }

// MOVIE='movieC'
 while ($row = oci_fetch_array($query, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {

 // data here

 }

// MOVIE='movieD'
 while ($row = oci_fetch_array($query, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {

 // data here

 }

// MOVIE='movieE'
 while ($row = oci_fetch_array($query, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {

 // data here

 }
```

Thanks - What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What if you had 10000000 movies? You need only 1 loop..

Answer (score 1):

Do collect first:

```
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($query, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
  $collect[]=$row;
}
```

then use that array often as you will

```
foreach($collect as $row) {
  // data here
}
```

And why you could only fetch a result set once?

Please read the given docs for that:

PDO http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php
MySqli http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

And maybe a little bit about to code an algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm

Comment: I dont know much PHP. but `$collect[]=$row;` doesnt feel right, there is no `$collect[i]` or something to avoid overwrite the same variable

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza `$collect[]=$row;` is equal to `array_push($collect,$row);` feels that better? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Comment: I currently have 5 queries with 5 recordsets - just wondering if there was a better way

Comment: We cant help you if you don't explain what is happening in the while loop. Right now is to vague.

Answer (score -1):

you can also do the below code why you need multiple while loop

```
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($query, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {

    swith($row){

    case 1 :
    //do here
    break;

    case 2 :
    //do here
    break;

          }

     }
```

Comment: I cant really use a case statement as the outputs are in different places on the page. I need seperate calls to the data based on the value

Comment: @Ronald yes you can do the separate calls on data based on values